# Etymology of "bodegón"

Tags: etimología

Can someone confirm the etymology of the Spanish word [bodegón](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodeg%C3%B3n)? I know that it is an augmentative of [bodega](https://www.spanishetym.com/search?query=bodega), which I could trace back to the 11th century. I do not know if it is from Old Spanish as well or if it is newer, from Modern or Standard Spanish; I wish to make this distinction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed an augmentative from **bodega**, as shown in the Diccionario de la Lengua Española:

[**bodegón**](https://dle.rae.es/bodeg%C3%B3n)

> Del *aum.* de **bodega**.
>
> 1. m. taberna.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!